# Getting an error message; Failed to load rescources: the server responded with a status of 500

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xampp, codeigniter-3

I am working creating an app and i notice that when i try to include ajax code in my work its not working...and this same code is working for the video tutorial am learning from it happened in two different video tutorials wen i get to anything relating to ajax.. and its quiet frustrating..
this i my code below.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Book List</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="row" align="right">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 table-responsive">
<table id="book-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Book Title</th>
                                    <th>Book Price</th>
                                    <th>Book Author</th>
                                    <th>Rating</th>
                                    <th>Publisher</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#book-table').DataTable({
            "ajax":{
                url: "<?php echo site_url("books/books_page") ?>",
                type: 'GET'
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the error am getting wen i try to inspect it using google chrome developer tools

[image]

Comment: what is the code for site_url("books/books_page") ?have you enble php errors ?

Comment: Am using a php frame work in building to app.. Site_url("books/books_page")  is the controller(books)  and method (books)   and i use it to load my view page..

Comment: Please click on "enter image description here" 
Above to view that image i posted to see the error am getting thanks

Comment: Please check your error log - c:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log

Comment: I have checked i dont understand wat am seeing dere

Comment: 1. Delete everything from that file (`c:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`), 2. make one more request, 3. copy and paste error in edited question here.

Comment: [Sat Mar 03 08:00:05.751293 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 5696:tid 668] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Mar 03 08:00:05.985685 2018] [core:warn] [pid 5696:tid 668] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

Comment: [Sat Mar 03 08:00:06.173180 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 5696:tid 668] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Mar 03 08:00:06.235681 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5696:tid 668] AH00455: Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.0.18 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Mar 03 08:00:06.235681 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5696:tid 668] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec 17 2016 10:42:52

Comment: [Sat Mar 03 08:00:06.235681 2018] [core:notice] [pid 5696:tid 668] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sat Mar 03 08:00:06.298170 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5696:tid 668] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7552
[Sat Mar 03 08:00:08.845050 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 7552:tid 608] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: [Sat Mar 03 08:00:09.251303 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 7552:tid 608] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Mar 03 08:00:09.485677 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7552:tid 608] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from console the url is wrong, put it as below:

```
            url: "<?php echo site_url("/books/books_page") ?>",
```